# Qt Creator reverted back to some previous version

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-touch, qt, qt-creator

I've had Qt Creator on my machine for quite a while, and after adding the necessary PPAs, I could use it for Ubuntu Touch, the Ubuntu SDK being installed and all. Yesterday, i noticed that Qt had been reverted back to some previous version. The Ubuntu SDK no longer exists, nor do the tools within Qt for UT. Its gone, all of it. The update manager had a few updates from the SDK team, a few plugins for Qt and a Qt Creator file (around 12mb), i ran the update, but everything remained the same.

How can this be sorted out? It's necessary that i get the SDK back.

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest update from [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/ubuntu_sdk_release/raring/main/base/qtcreator) on qtcreator, the ubuntu plugins for qtcreator are now located in a separate package called `qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu`.

Comment: thanks! but that's for 13.04, isn't it? also, in my case Qt Creator has been reverted to an older version, despite the change in folders the updates are not only applicable but also non-existent.